# Magento 2.3.5. Checkout - Custom attribute failed to save for logged in user

Tags: magento2.3, checkout, custom-attributes

I have an issue with a custom attribute in the shipping address failing to save for Logged In customers when he clicks on "Add new address" in checkout. If he uses an already saved address with a custom attribute then everything works. If a guest user is trying to finish checkout with a custom attribute field then it also works as expected. The issue is only for the logged-in user when he clicks on the "Add new address" button and tries to enter his address from checkout.

In developers console in network tab, the following call is failing - `/rest/es_es/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information` with the following error message -

```
"Error occurred during "shipping_address" processing. Error occurred during "extension_attributes" processing. Error occurred during "door_number" processing. The "array" value's type is invalid. The "string" type was expected. Verify and try again."
```

This is my `extension_attributes.xml` -

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="door_number" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

This is my `set-shipping-information-mixin.js` -

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, wrapper,quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setShippingInformationAction) {
        return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction, messageContainer) {
            var shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();

            if (shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] === undefined) {
                shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] = {};
            }

            if (shippingAddress.customAttributes !== undefined) {
                $.each(shippingAddress.customAttributes, function(key, value) {
                    if ($.isPlainObject(value)) {
                        value = value['value'];
                        key = this.attribute_code;
                    }

                    shippingAddress['customAttributes'][key] = value;
                    shippingAddress['extension_attributes'][key] = value;
                });
            }

            return originalAction(messageContainer);
        });
    };
});
```

What could be the reason why custom attributes are failing only for logged-in users when adding new address through checkout but working for logged-in customer saved addresses and also for guest users going through the checkout no issues appear. What I am missing?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to store extension attribute using plugin. Check this blog https://www.dckap.com/blog/extension-attributes-in-magento2/

Comment: Hello @RahulBarot, tried your link, using the plugin example in your given link it throws an error, that "Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 102"

Comment: Please check added answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow below steps to save custom field value.

Below code will be work for both the login and guest user. Also please create field in "quote_address" and "sales_order_address" table first. Here i have shown you code according to the field "customtype". Please change field according to yours.

> Step 1:- Create file extension_attributes.xml under path
> Zmage/Customfield/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface">
        <attribute code="customtype" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

> Step 2:- Create requirejs-config.js file under path
> Zmage/Customfield/view/frontend/

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default" : "Zmage_Customfield/js/shipping-save-processor-default-override"
        }
    }
};
```

> Step 3:- Create file shipping-save-processor-default-override.js under
> path Zmage/Customfield/view/frontend/web/js/

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager',
        'mage/storage',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-converter',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor'
    ],
    function (ko, $, quote, resourceUrlManager, storage, paymentService, methodConverter, errorProcessor) {
        'use strict';
        return {
            saveShippingInformation: function() {
                var payload = {

                addressInformation: {
                        shipping_address: quote.shippingAddress(),
                        shipping_method_code: quote.shippingMethod().method_code,
                        shipping_carrier_code: quote.shippingMethod().carrier_code,
                        extension_attributes: {
                            customtype: $('[name="custom_attributes[customtype]"]').val()
                        }
                    }
                };

                return storage.post(
                    resourceUrlManager.getUrlForSetShippingInformation(quote),
                    JSON.stringify(payload)
                ).done(
                    function (response) {
                        quote.setTotals(response.totals);
                        paymentService.setPaymentMethods(methodConverter(response.payment_methods));
                    }
                ).fail(
                    function (response) {
                        errorProcessor.process(response);
                    }
                );
            }
        };
    }
);
```

> Step 4:- Create di.xml file under path Zmage/Customfield/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="add_custom_field_checkout_form" type="Zmage\Customfield\Plugin\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
        <plugin name="save-in-quote" type="Zmage\Customfield\Plugin\Checkout\ShippingInformationManagementPlugin" sortOrder="12349"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\ToOrderAddress">
        <plugin name="item_quote_to_order_address" type="Zmage\Customfield\Plugin\ItemQuoteToOrderAddress"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Step 5:- Please create file LayoutProcessor.php under path
> Zmage/Customfield/Plugin/Checkout

Below code is for creating custom field in shipping address form.

```
<?php
namespace Zmage\Customfield\Plugin\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        $customAttributeCode = 'customtype';

        $customField = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                // customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                'customEntry' => null,
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
                'tooltip' => [
                    'description' => 'this is what the field is for',
                ],
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes' . '.' . $customAttributeCode,
            'label' => 'Custom type',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'sortOrder' => 10,
            'validation' => [
               'required-entry' => true
            ],
            'options' => [],
            'filterBy' => null,
            'customEntry' => null,
            'visible' => true,
        ];

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$customAttributeCode] = $customField;
 
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

> Step 6:- Create ShippingInformationManagementPlugin.php file under
> path Zmage/Customfield/Plugin/Checkout

Below code is for saving custom field value in quote address table.

```
<?php

namespace Zmage\Customfield\Plugin\Checkout;

/**
 * Class ShippingInformationManagementPlugin
 * @package Oye\Deliverydate\Model\Checkout
 */
class ShippingInformationManagementPlugin
{
    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    ) {
        $extAttributes = $addressInformation->getExtensionAttributes();
        $customType = $extAttributes->getCustomtype();
        $shippingAddress = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress();
        $shippingAddress->setCustomtype($customType);
    }
}
```

> Step 7:- Create ItemQuoteToOrderAddress.php file under path
> Zmage/Customfield/Plugin

Below code is for saving custom field value from quote address to order address table.

```
<?php
namespace Zmage\Customfield\Plugin;
 
class ItemQuoteToOrderAddress
{
    public function aroundConvert(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\ToOrderAddress $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $object,
        $data = []
    ) {
        $orderAddress = $proceed($object, $data);
        if($object->getCustomtype()){
            $orderAddress->setCustomtype($object->getCustomtype());
        }
        
        return $orderAddress;
    }
}
```

Above code is practically tested and it is working fine. Please check and let me know.